# IIS7 HTTP to HTTPS redirect makes asp.net API fail with "document not in recognised format" "Client proxy code is empty!"

Tags: asp.net, soap, iis-7, redirect, https

We publish an asp.net API on:

```
http://API.domain.com/v3/service.svc
https://API.domain.com/v3/service.svc
```

Had a problem last week with a corrupt SSL certificate which meant connecting to the HTTPS ref fails with an internet explorer connection problem. HTTP ref was fine, was confirmed the SSL corruption was the issue.

A customer that should have been using HTTPS never noticed, logs confirmed they are actually using HTTP for authentication and data.

When testing with WCF STORM (test app I used to test method calls) I could recreate the issue i.e HTTP ok & HTTPS fails. Installing a backup certificate resolved the problem instantly, everything back to normal operation.

So I started looking at HTTP to HTTPS redirects. Got it up and running using http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/redirect_http_to_https_iis_7 (i.e the change to web.config).

When browsing to my API HTTP and HTTPS url, everything worked as expected.

When using WCF STORM to I get the message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The document at the url http://API.domain.com/v3/service.svc was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:

- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL http://API.domain.com/v3/service.svc?disco&disco could not be found.'.
  - The document format is not recognized.
- Report from 'http://API.domain.com/v3/service.svc' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
   at System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.DiscoverAny(String url)
   at WcfStorm.DynamicProxy.ServiceClientProxyFactory.(Option`1 )
   at WcfStorm.DynamicProxy.ServiceClientProxyFactory.DiscoverEndpoint(Option`1 cfgOption)
   at WcfStorm.Model.WcfServiceModel.(ServiceClientProxyFactory )
   at WcfStorm.Lib.Common.BgWorker`2.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
Client proxy code is empty!
```

I remember one of the developers telling me that the AUTHENTICATION uses SSL but the SOAP messages are transmitted over HTTP. Therefore I suspect the HTTP to HTTPS redirection has caused this issue as its forcing the SOAP messages to use HTTPS and the API has not been configured to do this .... I'm guessing? Developer explained that its recommended that APIs using HTTP for transmitting the SOAP data after authentication using SSL to confirm credentials.

**Questions:**

1. How do we force the SOAP data to be transmitted over HTTPS if this is deemed the solution?
2. If this is not possible how do i deployed HTTP to HTTPS redirect within the environment above ?
3. Any other way to force HTTPS onto end users / disabled HTTP and / or redirect to HTTPS ?

Thank you for any help.